# Deploy Vosao in Capedwarf Beta 3

Tags: google-app-engine, capedwarf

I get a lot of errors when trying to deploy Vosao in Capedwarf Beta 3:

Here's the complete log:

http://pastebin.com/2z35pEvE

- java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/velocity/tools/view/jsp/VelocityViewTag (Module "org.apache.velocity.tools:main" from local module loader

Looks like CD can't locate the Apache Velocity dependency?

Anyway, I still tried accessing the context root:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9990/vosaocms-0.9.14
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1:9990/vosaocms-0.9.14/vosaocms
```

I guess there was really a problem in the deployment.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Velocity in your app?

I would say yes, as it looks like it overlaps with CapeDwarf's Velocity usage - we use it to rended admin console.

Try removing the Velocity libs.

But I will also fix this in CapeDwarf, so the two libs won't overlap.
Leaving you with your own version of Velocity then.

Comment: This should now be fixed in upstream master.